# Why can I only add data in my database when I hash it to md5?

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, hash

I have a function where I enter data from a html form in a database. When i try and submit the function it doesn't enter the value. But when I hash my variable to md5 it does enter the value to the database? Does anyone know why this might be?

Here is my function:

```
 function damage()
{
    require 'mysql.php';
    $today = date("Y-m-d");
    $cost = $_POST["cost"];
    $damage = $_POST["damage"];
    $query = "INSERT INTO schade VALUES (NULL, '$cost', '$damage', '$today')";
    mysql_query($query, $db) or die ("Vul alle velden in!"); 
    echo("Gelukt");
}
damage();
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the html code?

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injections. You should read on [how to prevent them in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/53114). This may also fix your problem.

Comment: Replace `die ("Vul alle velden in!")` with `die (mysql_error());` and you will know the reason behind your error.

Comment: <body>
<form>
 Cost: <input type="kosten" name="kosten">
 What is the damage? <input type="typeschade" name="typeschade">
</form>

<input type="submit" value="Send">
 </div>
 <?php


 
  function damage()
  {
   require 'mysql.php';
   $today = date("Y-m-d");
   $cost= $_POST["kosten"];
   $damage= $_POST["typeschade"];
   $query = "INSERT INTO schade VALUES (NULL, '$kosten', '$schade', '$today')";
   mysql_query($query, $db) or die ("Vul alle velden in!"); 
   echo("Gelukt");
  }
  damage();
 
 ?>
</body>
</html>

Comment: Add this to the question, it's unreadable in the comment.

Comment: Explicitly state the columns that you're INSERTing INTO :: `INSERT INTO schade (foo1, foo2, foo3, foo4) VALUES (NULL, '$cost', '$damage', '$today') `